# implement a method that takes 3 boolean args

Tags: java

I'm studying "Programming in Java An Interdisciplinary Approach by Sedgewick and Wayne". The following question is giving me a bit of a challenge to implement.

Write a static method odd() that takes three boolean inputs and returns true if an odd number of inputs are true, and false otherwise.

```
private static boolean odd(boolean x, boolean y, boolean z)
    {
        if((x && y) && z)
           return true;
        else if((x) && !y && !z)
            return true;
        else if((y) && !x && !z)
            return true;
        else if((z) && !x && !y)
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }
```

Could I have implemented this a different way?

Comment: Sure you could.  One of the fun parts about programming is that there are many, many ways to solve any problem.

Comment: ug_ and eran seem to be very efficient ways to implement this algorithm thanks for your feedback...

Comment: You accepted the wrong answer.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels what do you mean? I ran the code and it seems to work. Incrementing a int and doing a modulus operation should be faster than the XOR operation no?

Comment: No, modulo operations are generally somewhat slow as they are divisions internally. Plus you get the overhead from casting to int.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the simplest way would be to make your booleans to `int` values and add them up.

```
private static boolean odd(boolean x, boolean y, boolean z) {
    int sum = 0;
    if(x) sum++;
    if(y) sum++;
    if(z) sum++;

    // check if its odd.
    return sum % 2 != 0;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use XOR :

```
private static boolean odd(boolean x, boolean y, boolean z)
{
    return x ^ y ^ z;
}
```